# MouseHover/MouseLeave event on the whole entire window

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mouseleave, mousehover

I have Form subclass with handlers for `MouseHover` and `MouseLeave`. When the pointer is on the background of the window, the events work fine, but when the pointer moves onto a control **inside** the window, it causes a `MouseLeave` event.

Is there anyway to have an event covering the whole window.

(.NET 2.0, Visual Studio 2005, Windows XP.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the mouse leave event is fired one option is to check for the current position of the pointer and see if it within the form area. I am not sure whether a better option is available.

Edit: We have a similar question which might be of interest to you. [How to detect if the mouse is inside the whole form and child controls in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986529/how-to-detect-if-the-mouse-is-inside-the-whole-form-and-child-controls-in-c)

Comment: So if I register the same handler for MouseEnter and MouseLeave for *all* controls inside a window (including inside panels), then have that handler check the mouse position to detect a change of inside/outside and call the "real" enter/leave handler. Good idea, thanks.

Comment: I added an example of how to use just one MouseEnter and MouseLeave event for the entire form.  Let me know if that works for you

Comment: Good idea. But if the contained Control is on the border it won't work. (Give credit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19361582/939213) to the user who noticed it.)

Answer (score 11):

Ovveride the MouseLeave event to not trigger so long as the mouse enters a child control

```
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ClientRectangle.Contains(this.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)))
            return;
        else
        {
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no good way to make MouseLeave reliable for a container control.  Punt this problem with a timer:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 200;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private bool mEntered;

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Point pos = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        bool entered = this.ClientRectangle.Contains(pos);
        if (entered != mEntered) {
            mEntered = entered;
            if (!entered) {
                // Do your leave stuff
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your user control create a mousehover Event for your control like this, (or other event type) like this

```
private void picBoxThumb_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Call Parent OnMouseHover Event
    OnMouseHover(EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

On your WinForm which hosts the UserControl have this for the UserControl to Handle the MouseOver so place this in your Designer.cs

```
this.thumbImage1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.ThumbnailMouseHover);
```

Which calls this method on your WinForm

```
private void ThumbnailMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ThumbImage thumb = (ThumbImage) sender;

}
```

Where ThumbImage is the type of usercontrol