# C# MouseEnter event activating even if something is in front of it?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, custom-controls, mouseenter

I am making a custom button (Windows Forms) in Visual Studio. When I hover over the button, it triggers the `mouseenter` event like it should, but when I hover over the text, it triggers the `mouseleave` event when it is still over the button. How would I get around this?

Comment: This is by design. Your mouse has left the control it was currently over and entered another control.

Comment: i know, how would i make it not do that, or make an invisible box in front of it that captures all the events?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MouseEnter and MouseLeave events from a Panel and its child controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576021/mouseenter-and-mouseleave-events-from-a-panel-and-its-child-controls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text you are talking about, is it the text of the button or some other text control?
If its of the button then you should not face the problem. If its another control just add mouse hover event to it and call the same function as you were calling in mouse hover event of the button.

Comment: its a label, so not a part of the system button. this is what i ended up resorting to

Comment: You can possibly create a function for the task and call that function for the mousehover event of both the button and the label.

Comment: Why not just have one method and map it to two events?
private void Control_Hover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Whatever you feel like doing
}

// In the event mapping

Label1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(Control_Hover);
Button.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(Control_Hover);

Answer (score 0):

So you have a button once the mouse enters the button the color should change you can achieve this my **mouse hover**

```
private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     button1.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Where as the text hover you wanted the mouse cursor to leave that location. Is that right? 
If yes then the code is

```
    private void label1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
        Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
    }
```

I doubt the second one, i guess you want something else. Please do let me know.
Cheers!!

Comment: when the cursor hovers over the button it works fine. it goes over the text, the button activates the mouseleave event, and i need it to not do that.

Comment: Explain me this "it goes over the text, the button activates the mouseleave event, and i need it to not do that"

Your cursor goes over the textbox, hence the button activate the mouseleave event? How. I went over the label. Only thing happened was my mouse was kicked out of the zone.??

Comment: i have a control named myControl, and a label inside it called myLabel. When i go over myControl it runs the mouseenter event, when i go over myLabel which is right over it, it activayes myControl's mouseleave event

Comment: add MouseEnterEvent to your myLabel. The same event which was in myControl.

Now in leave even of myControl you can see if the sender is myControl or myLabel depending where you want act your event.