# WinForms C# Button Visibility

Tags: c#, button, visibility

I have a Panel with 2 buttons on it. What i'm trying to do is, when the mouse is inside the panel area then the buttons are visible, and when the mouse location is off the panel area the buttons are not visible.

I'm using the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events on the panel.

On `MouseEnter` i do `button.Show()` and on `MouseLeave` i do `button.Hide()`;

This seems simple, but when the buttons are visible (the mouse is inside the panel area) they are not clickable (click events are not triggered).

Some debugging shows that the when the mouse is over the button, the events `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` are continuously being called.

Any suggestion on this ? This should be so easy to be done that i'm actually without ideas.

Comment: Try adding button.Enabled = true;

Comment: Forget to say that the button is being enabled is `MouseEnter` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because when your mouse is over any button event `MouseLeave` is fired on panel, so buttons are again invisible and mouse is back on panel thus firing immediately `MouseEnter` and showing them back.

Fix your logic by adding some flag that checks in `MouseLeave` event if you are on any control that belongs to that panel, if so do not hide them.

Edit: here you have an example to fix your issue - [MouseEnter and MouseLeave events from a Panel and its child controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576021/mouseenter-and-mouseleave-events-from-a-panel-and-its-child-controls).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution presented in the other topic referred by gzaxx

```
 protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ClientRectangle.Contains(this.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)))
                return;
            else
            {
                base.OnMouseLeave(e);
            }
        }
```