# ToolStrip control never fire Enter/Leave event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a movable panel in WinForms. I use a ToolStrip as a titlebar in the panel. I'll use the ToolStrip to move the panel as well as indicating the panel is "active" or not. So when the panel is active, I want to change the ToolStrip's BackColor to Red.

UPDATE: The panel will host other controls, such as a listview. I want the panel being shown as "active" when the hosted control get focus, kind like the behavior of a normal window, whereas the window becomes the panel, and the titlebar becomes the ToolStrip.

When the panel is considered as "active"

1. hosted control get focus
2. ToolStrip being MouseDown/MouseClick
3. ToolStrip being dragged by mouse

The idea is capturing ToolStrip's Enter/Leave event to change the color, but it seems those events are never fired.

Are those events truly never fired? Should I capture other events?

Comment: Neither a panel nor ToolStrip can receive the focus.  So, no, the Enter event won't run.  What does "active" mean?

Answer (score 0):

mmmm there are a few ways to do this I guess.

You could use hook into the IMessageFilter message and see if its over your toolstrip/panel and then act accordingly (WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_LBUTTONUP etc - see windows documentation on WIndows Messages for hex message codes for all windows messages). There are many examples about - for example: [How to detect if the mouse is inside the whole form and child controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986529/how-to-detect-if-the-mouse-is-inside-the-whole-form-and-child-controls-in-c)

Setting a boolen based on whether active or not, an override in the paint can allow the colour settings - or simply flip them along with/instead of the boolean. Same for moving, set a boolean for move active/or not - and then allow WM_MOUSEMOVE to move the form/panel (or not) as needed.

Comment: How can i get (keyboard event) KeyDown or KeyUp or KeyPress event in ToolStripMenuItem.. Even GotFoucs is better... Is there any way to chech if user Using arrow keys Focus or Enter a ToolStripMenuItem ??